# How do I stop search engines from changing my searches?

Tags: search-engines

Sometimes search engines will give you a suggestion link for what they think you meant, and I'm fine with this. However, when the search engine, right off the bat, ignores half the words in my search, and makes me put each word I type in quotes to get what I actually searched for, that infuriates me.

Is there any search engine or browser plugin I can use to stop it from ignoring me or messing with what I type?

[image: This is ridiculous]

Comment: You can use "speech marks" to include *exactly* your search string in results, in Google and maybe other search engines. Try it out!

Comment: **Moderator Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: 1. Read browser help to turn off search suggestions. 2. Use quotes.

Comment: Quotes do not work. It doesn't search for what I typed, and instead searches for synonyms, misspellings, and other irrelevant garbage.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like we should use "Speech marks" all the time if we want it to actually search for what we type in.  It is what it is I guess.  This is the price we pay for free searches.  Not the end of the world really considering how much work those search engines do and how lost we would be without them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).